# Reject certain query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, my.cnf

I can't find where in the code a query is triggered and was wondering if there is a mysql configuration that will reject that query when it is triggered? For example, in my situation it is `UPDATE table SET col1 = NULL, col2 = NULL, col3 = NULL` ... PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: You could add a `BEFORE UPDATE` [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) to your `table`, but really I think you ought to track down where the `UPDATE` is in your code.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not my code and it's a nightmare to track it down :(

Comment: @eggyal: How in this situation an `BEFORE UPDATE` will look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html); just call a non-existent procedure to raise an error when the desired criteria are met.

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER reject_null_table_update BEFORE UPDATE ON table FOR EACH ROW
IF
      NEW.col1 IS NULL
  AND NEW.col2 IS NULL
  AND NEW.col3 IS NULL
  -- etc
THEN
  CALL raise_error();
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Sorry for stupid questions, but I never used triggers in mysql... Can I customize the message in `raise_error()`?